# Not catching second return value in type assertion causes runtime panic

Tags: go, panic

Below code causes runtime panic on second Println if assertion fails and second value "OK" is not provided for assignment for return value. however, if the second value is provided runtime panic does not occur. How not assigning return value can cause the panic? is there any good resource to learn about panics in Go?

```
var i interface{} = "hello" 

    f, ok := i.(float64) //  no runtime panic
    fmt.Println(f, ok)

    f = i.(float64) // panic
    fmt.Println(f)
```

Update 1: To make the question more clear.
I wanted to know how panic occurs at runtime when the second return value is not caught 'ok' and panic does not occur when the second return value is caught (f is assigned to zero value and ok is false)

Update 2: From the discussion I understood, assigning two return values handles the runtime panic, in short, it acts as a safeguard. Marking the answer as correct.

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how type assertions are defined to work, nothing shocking about that.

[Language Spec: Type assertions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

> For an expression `x` of [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) and a type `T`, the primary expression
>
> ```
> x.(T)
> ```
>
> asserts that `x` is not `nil` and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`. The notation `x.(T)` is called a *type assertion*.
>
> [...] If the type assertion holds, the value of the expression is the value stored in `x` and its type is `T`. **If the type assertion is false, a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) occurs.**
>
> [...] A type assertion used in an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = x.(T)
> v, ok := x.(T)
> var v, ok = x.(T)
> var v, ok T1 = x.(T)
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of `ok` is `true` if the assertion holds. Otherwise it is `false` and the value of `v` is the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for type `T`. **No run-time panic occurs in this case.**

In your case `i` holds a dynamic value of type `string`, and yet you try to type-assert a value of `float64` from it. So the type assertion is false, and per spec a run-time panic occurs. If you'd write `i.(string)` => this type assertion is true, so no run-time panic would occur in this case.

If you use the special form (assigning 2 return values), it will never panic, rather if type assertion does not hold, first value will be the zero value of the type you try to assert, second value will be an untyped boolean value `false`.

Comment: Thanks @icza, but I want to know what generates panic, as per the golang tour, panic occurs at  like `i.(string)` . how this line knows we are not catching second return value?

Comment: See edited answer. `i` holds a `string` value, not `float64`. The type assertion is false, that's why it panics.

Comment: but in first case also `f, ok := i.(float64) //  no runtime panic` type assertion fails but no runtime panic occurs here, how this is handled by assigning second return value only

Comment: @AkshayNaik that's the purpose of the second value, you can think of it as a safeguard against panic and in addition also an indicator of the success/failure of the type assertion.

Comment: @mkopriva, can you provide any reference where I can read more about such safeguards.

Comment: @AkshayNaik you can think of it this way as well: If you don't use the `comma-ok` idiom the run-time has no way, other than to panic, to tell you that your assertion is wrong. If, on the other hand, you use the `comma-ok` idiom the run-time doesn't need to panic because it can signal a wrong type assertion with the second value. If the run-time woudn't panic in case of a wrong type assertion used without the second return value than your program would continue to work as if everything's ok and it would produce incorrect output and people would die.

Comment: @AkshayNaik you can, and you should, read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec), as far as safeguards are concerned it was just a suggestion of how you can think about the type assertion + comma-ok idiom. If you're unsatisfied with icza's answer you might want to turn to the go-nuts mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an underscore for variables you don't need.

```
var i interface{} = "hello" 

    f, ok := i.(float64) //  no runtime panic
    fmt.Println(f, ok)

    f, _ = i.(float64) // no runtime panic
    fmt.Println(f)

    f = i.(float64) // panic
    fmt.Println(f)
```

Comment: Yes, but catching second return value is optional for successful assertion they why runtime panic for failure cases? in short what causes runtime panic here? below code runs successfully with no second assignment 
`f := i.(string) //  no runtime panic
    fmt.Println(f, ) `

Comment: @AkshayNaik Runtime panic is caused by using the single-return-value form of type assertion with an invalid conversion. When golang runs its internal type assertion code, it checks how many arguments are to be returned. That's how it knows whether to panic or return the zero value. (Sorry I'm 2-3 years late with this answer!)